# Extracting interval based on data/tag

Tags: pandas

```
times = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2020-08-05','2020-08-12', '2020-08-16', '2020-08-22', '2020-08-30', '2020-09-11', '2020-09-20']))
event = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'v': event}, index=times)
```

Above is my dataframe. I am trying to extract interval where the value switched from 0 to 1.

My ideal out put in above case would be :

```
[['2020-09-11 00:00:00', '2020-09-20 00:00:00'],
 ['2020-08-12 00:00:00', '2020-08-16 00:00:00']]
```

How I am approaching:
I am iterating over the df in reverse and trying to find first occurrence of '1'. 
There after I am looking for first occurrence of 0. These correspond to the first interval.
I am repeating above over the df.

But, the output, I am getting is:

```
[['2020-09-11 00:00:00', '2020-09-20 00:00:00'],
 ['2020-08-12 00:00:00', '2020-08-22 00:00:00']]
```

I know that the issue is because of consecutive 1 in the timeseries. But, not able to find the workaround. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: some problem with solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#filter last consecutive values    
df2 = df[df['v'].ne(df['v'].shift(-1))]

#filter 0,1 pattern
m1 = df['v'].eq(0) & df['v'].shift(-1).eq(1)
m2 = df['v'].eq(1) & df['v'].shift().eq(0)

#after filtering sorting index
df2 = df[m1 | m2].sort_index(ascending=False)

#convert index to list
L = [list(x) for x in zip(df2.index[1::2], df2.index[::2])]
print (L)
[[Timestamp('2020-09-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-09-20 00:00:00')], 
 [Timestamp('2020-08-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-08-16 00:00:00')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#find location where there is a change from 0 to 1
res = df.loc[df.v.diff().eq(1)].index
#get the preceding value 
out = [[ent-1,ent] for ent in df.index.get_indexer_for(res)]
[df.index[entry] for entry in out]
[DatetimeIndex(['2020-08-12', '2020-08-16'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None),
 DatetimeIndex(['2020-09-11', '2020-09-20'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)]
```